# RecursionError when using gtts on Python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am using the gtts(google text to speech) package to turn several Chinese Text to Speech. However, I got a lot of RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

The code is easy:

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS(text=sentence, lang='zh')
tts.save(r"E:\Project\audioData\zh%d.wav"%(1))
```

The full error messeage is showed as photo
[Error Messeage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXHzH.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Independent Study\Project\test.py", line 3, in <module>
tts = gTTS(text=sentence, lang='zh')
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 97, in __init__
text_parts = self._tokenize(text, self.MAX_CHARS)
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 169, in _tokenize
min_parts += self._minimize(p, " ", max_size)
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 178, in _minimize
return [thestring[:idx]] + self._minimize(thestring[idx:], delim, max_size)
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 178, in _minimize
return [thestring[:idx]] + self._minimize(thestring[idx:], delim, max_size)
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 178, in _minimize
return [thestring[:idx]] + self._minimize(thestring[idx:], delim, max_size)
[Previous line repeated 983 more times]
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 176, in _minimize
if self._len(thestring) > max_size:
File "C:\Users\Yuchen Liu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
packages\gtts\tts.py", line 154, in _len
return len(unicode(text))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please do not post photos. Please post the text.

Comment: Some code would also be helpful.

Comment: The error is not caused by that code, it shows the complete code.

Comment: The error do caused by this code, the sentence is written by chinese

Comment: Does your sentence contain a 100+ character word in it? That's the only way I can see for the error to be occurring after looking at the library's code. For it to recurse forever like that, it seems to be trying to process a string that starts with a space followed by at least 99 non-space characters.

Comment: @Blckknght , with Chinese text, that could be possible.  I noticed in `_tokenize` that their punctuation includes the Chinese period, but not the Chinese comma (，). In Chinese writing, commas are used more like periods in English. Also, I rarely see spaces.  perhaps if there had been some sort of leading indent, or maybe a space after a period, it would be easy to have `" "` and then 99 characters interspersed with unrecognized commas and no spaces.  LiuYuchen , can you print the text you were using please?

Answer (score 0):

The correct terminology is:

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS("sentence",lang = "zh")

tts.save("sentence.mp3")
```